# non-nullable local variable userModel must be assigned

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
FutureEither<UserModel> signInWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
          await googleUser?.authentication;
      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
      );

      final userCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

      final user = userCredential.user!;
      UserModel userModel;
      if (userCredential.additionalUserInfo!.isNewUser) {
        userModel = UserModel(
          email: user.email!,
          id: user.uid,
          img: user.photoURL!,
          username: user.displayName!,
        );
        await saveUserData(userModel);
       
      } else {
        final userDoc = await getUserData(user.email!);
        userDoc.fold((l) => null, (r) {
          userModel = UserModel.fromJson(r);
         
        });
      }
      return right(userModel);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e, st) {
      return left(
        Failure(e.message ?? "Bilinmeyen bir hata oluştu", st),
      );
    } catch (e, st) {
      return left(
        Failure(e.toString(), st),
      );
    }
  }
```

I made the assignment but I still face the null problem

Comment: You don't have a "null problem", you have a potentially-uninitialized-variable problem.  Yes, you assign `userModel` in the callback to `userDoc.fold`, but there the compiler cannot guarantee that that callback is ever called (what if `userDoc` is empty?).  If you can guarantee that `userDoc` will never be empty, then just declare `userModel` to be `late`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `late` to assing before read time, or make it nullable.

```dart
 late UserModel userModel;
```

or

```dart
  UserModel? userModel;
```

More about [understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)